# trying to create a loop that returns a logo in the list images and the name cryptolist

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

i have a Widget that is called CoinCard which shows a cyrptoLogo,name and price.
now instead of calling that widget 3 times and providing image and a name, i wanted to create a loop which will return a image from images and the name from cryptoList. code below:

[image]

```
List<String> images = [
  "Bitcoin.svg.png",
  "256px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png",
  "litecoin-ltc-logo.png"
];
const List<String> cryptoList = ['BTC', 'ETH', 'LTC'];

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<Widget> getCard() {
    List<CoinCard> cards = [];

    for (String image in images) {
      cards.add(
        CoinCard(
          cryptoname: "ggg",
          logo: image,
          price: "5001918556",
        ),
      );
    }
    return cards;
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `ListView.builder` to create dynamic list

example :

```
class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  List<String> images = [
  "Bitcoin.svg.png",
  "256px-Ethereum_logo_2014.svg.png",
  "litecoin-ltc-logo.png"
];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ListView.builder(
      itemCount:images.length ,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) => CoinCard(
          cryptoname: "ggg",
          logo: images[index],
          price: "5001918556",
        ),
      );
  }
}
```